# Have default constructor access some mutable state without using globals

Tags: c++

I'd like to have an Allocator class that can be constructed via its default constructor, as a lot of STL containers attempt to create allocators like this.

However, I'd also like the Allocators to share certain common resources.

My current solution is to have a global variable representing the shared state that the individual objects grab on initialization. Eg, I'm doing something like this:

```
const int start = 0;

template<class T>
class Counter() {
 public:
  Counter() : x_(start) {}

  int increment() {
    return x_++;
  }

 private:
  int x_;
};

void SetStart(int s) {
  start = s;
}
```

Is there any way around using globals for this kind of setup? I thought it might be possible to create some kind of manager type with a subtype whose constructor accesses the appropriate resource, but as inner classes can't access member variables of outer classes in C++ I'm not sure how this would work.

Comment: Just use `static` variables.

Comment: @PawełStawarz I'd like to avoid statics as well since they feel pretty much just like namespace-d globals (and I already have my code in an actual `namespace`), but actually that also won't work because the class is templatized and I want shared access across different types. I'll update the toy snippet to reflect that.

Comment: There's really no way around this, you're basically asking to have globals without using globals.  Globals are not inherently bad so long as you understand their pitfalls (threading issues etc.).

Answer (score 3):

Basically, with [CRTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern#Object_counter) you can keep track of the count in a base class and use `template template` parameters to maintain the ability to use a class template as the derived type.

```
template <template <typename> class T>
class counter
{
public:
    counter() { ++count;  }
protected:
    static int count;
};
template <template <typename> class T> int counter<T>::count(0);

template <typename T>
class X : counter<X>
{
public:
    X() : x_(count) {}
private:
    int x_;
};
```

...

```
X<int> x;  // x_ initialized to 1
X<int> x2; // x_ initialized to 2
```

Comment: I having some trouble digesting the code, but this seems like _not_ what I'm looking for. Ie, with this, won't an `X<int>` and `X<double>` have separate counts, as opposed to sharing the same one?

Comment: @alecbenzer yes. However, you can have `X<int>` and `X<double>` share the same count by changing `counter` to a non-template class. i.e. declaring `X` this way, `template<typename T> class X : counter { /*...*/ };`

Answer (score 0):

Well why not just define an "*allocator*" <sup>1</sup> class if you need it?

```
template<typename T> class someTemplatedClass;
class myAllocator{
      template<typename T> friend class someTemplatedClass;

      static unsigned int someNumber;
};
unsigned int myAllocator::someNumber = 0;
```

Then you can make use of it inside your class:

```
template<typename T>
class someTemplatedClass{ 
   int someVariable;

   public:
      void write(){cout<<someVariable<<endl;};
      someTemplatedClass(){someVariable = myAllocator::someNumber++;};
};
```

The counter will persist thru all the specializations (since it's not by itself templated). The counter will also be invisible outside of the class scope, since `someNumber` is in fact `private`. You could also make `myAllocator` a **singleton** just for the sake of user-friendliness.

Or, if you need it - you could define a `static void set(const int value)` setter function that will let you set from what number the instance counter starts.

```
someTemplatedClass<int> array[10];
for(unsigned int i=0;i<10;i++)
   array[i].write();
someTemplatedClass<float> array2[5];
for(unsigned int i=0;i<5;i++)
   array2[i].write();
```

should print out numbers from `0` to `14`, so the **total** count of **all** the instances of `someTemplatedClass`.

---

<sup>1</sup> the example's not even near an allocator class, but you mentionned it, so maybe the counter is just an example and it'll really end up being an allocator.

Comment: I know my example's not an allocator -- I was trying to give a simple example illustrating what I'm trying to do. Instead of a class that counts up from a shared base value, I have allocators that allocate space from a shared resource.

Comment: @alecbenzer well then this should suit your needs.